# WKWebView iOS 15 is not responding to select element HTML

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios15

WKWebView is not responding to a simple HTML select tag.

```
let html = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>

        <select>
          <option value="viper">Viper</option>
          <option value="mamba">Mamba</option>
          <option value="cobra">Cobra</option>
          <option value="coastaltaipan">Coastal Taipan</option>
        </select>

        </body>
        </html>
        """
 webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

In iOS 14 and 13, the keyboard is showing with the options but in iOS 15 nothing is showing, I tested the same HTML on a normal Safari browser and it's working fine and shows a popup with options.